# How to pass an instance of another class when initializing an instance of a class?

Tags: c#, class

```
    public class A
    {
        public C instanceOfCInA;
        public double a;
        public double b;
    }
    public class B
    {
        public C instanceOfCInB;
        public A instanceOfAInB;
    }

    public class C
    {
        //not important
    }
```

How do I pass instanceOfCInB into instanceOfAInB's instanceOfCInA?

Comment: You just pass it. See marked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

use constructor (ctor) and use instance of the other class as parameter. Example for C in A:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            C c = new C();
            A a = new A(c);
            B b = new B(c, a);
        }
    }


    public class A
    {
        public A(C c)
        {
            instanceOfCInA = c;
        }

        public C      instanceOfCInA;
        public double a;
        public double b;
    }

    public class B
    {
        public B(C c, A a)
        {
           instanceOfCInB = c;
           instanceOfAInB = a;
        }

        public C instanceOfCInB;
        public A instanceOfAInB;
    }

    public class C
    {
        //not important
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not do
C c = new C();  
A a = new A(c);
inside public class B
It will throw an error saying "a field initializer cannot reference the non -static field, method, or property"

Comment: @Gloria i am not sure what you are doing. i updated the answer to make it more clear what has to be done.